# Consume SOAP/SSO using C#

Tags: c#, .net, soap, single-sign-on

Which is the easiest way to consume a WSDL SOAP/SSO using C# ?

This is a third party system and i get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResponse xmlns="http://WebService-MultiLogin-2013/">
      <RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResult>
        <EstadosMDL>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Nome>string</Nome>
          <Sigla>string</Sigla>
        </EstadosMDL>
        <EstadosMDL>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Nome>string</Nome>
          <Sigla>string</Sigla>
        </EstadosMDL>
      </RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResult>
    </RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is how i'm calling it:

```
public AdminMaster.RetornaEstadosPorMarca.Estados ssoEstados = new AdminMaster.RetornaEstadosPorMarca.Estados();

ssoEstados.RetornaEstadosPorMarca(Library.Configuracoes.ChaveSSO, Convert.ToInt16(Library.Configuracoes.Marca));
```

I have already tried to receive it as a string and format it to use as XML but it didn't work because of `<soap:Body>` and `<soap:Envelope>`, i get an error because i have the ':' on the name and i don't think that's the easiest way to do it.

So, how do i access the information from the response ? Is there another way ?

EDIT:

After several hours and tests i finally found the problem, "my" SOAP also gives me a class to create a object to receive the response, i only had to use it:

```
//Here i have the object with the methods
private Library.ssoEstados.Estados objEstadosSSO = new Library.ssoEstados.Estados();

//Here i have the object to receive the response    
private Library.ssoEstados.EstadosMDL[] objEstadosMDL;
```

Than it was only a matter of read the values i wanted and send it to my own object.

Comment: The best way is to use "Add Service Reference". See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: Hey @JohnSaunders, thanks for the help, i managed to find my way out after several tests, i had to create an object provided by the SOAP to receive the response.

Answer (score -1):

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(inputXml);
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
namespaces.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://tempuri.org/");
XmlNode accountNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns2:RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResponse/RetornaEstadosPorMarcaResult", namespaces);
XmlNode xnlAccount = accountNode.ChildNodes[0];
if (xnlAccount != null)
{
    XmlDocument xAccount = new XmlDocument();
    xAccount.LoadXml(xnlAccount.InnerText);
}
```

inputXml is a string containing your response xml.